# Android Notification Issues relating to time

Tags: notifications, 7.1-nougat, google-pixel

Over the past few weeks, I've had a serious increase in issues related to notifications on my Pixel, running Android 7.1.2. I'm beginning to suspect some sort of larger overarching problem, and I'm curious as to what the technical minds at Android Enthusiasts think.

My problems:

1) Notifications appear anywhere between 1 hour and 2 days late.

2) Clicking on notifications usually doesn't work, and sometimes presents the activity for the notification hours or days later. (example: I was at a CostCo and clicked on the location aware notification from the Google App, yesterday. This morning I was simply using my phone and then the Google Maps page for CostCo finally appeared.)

3) Do not disturb has failed to turn off at the appropriate time. (I set Do Not Disturb on Total Silence for one hour, eleven minutes after the time it was suppoed to turn off I looked at my phone, tried to change the volume, and the status bar appeared explaining the phone was on Total Silence for -11 more minutes. That's a negative eleven. In this instance, my sim card was out at the time, but I don't think that should have affected it.)

What could be causing these issues? Is it something timing related like I hypothesize?

**Edit:** I have rebooted multiple times and am fully up to date.

Comment: Have you taken any recent system updates?  Have you rebooted after any recent app updates?  I seem to have minor issues after system updates and a reboot clears it up.

Comment: I have rebooted multiple times and am fully up to date. Edited post.

Comment: My wife is having the same issues with her phone, an LG G5 on Nougat as well. Verizon has now sent her two replacements that are having the same issue. No resolution in sight.

Comment: @Andrew sorry to hear that! Try and follow this question to see if there's a solution later.